# Error in Python Keras Librosa Neural Network Music Analysis: Unidentified Variable in Scikit Import

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, librosa

Recently, I have been attempting to complete an experiment whereby a neural network music analysis program is created with Keras and the number of layers in the neural network is modified to find the effect on performance. My source for the program is the website below:

https://medium.com/@navdeepsingh_2336/identifying-the-genre-of-a-song-with-neural-networks-851db89c42f0

I have recently previously encountered several errors concerning my program and, on the advice of another developer on Stack Overflow, have decided to enlist the assistance of the Scikit library section.

The code is shown here:

```
import librosa
import librosa.feature
import librosa.display
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,        
StratifiedShuffleSplit, StratifiedKFold



def display_mfcc(song):
    y, _ = librosa.load(song)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    librosa.display.specshow(mfcc, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(song)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def extract_features_song(f):
    y, _ = librosa.load(f)

    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y)
    mfcc /= np.amax(np.absolute(mfcc))

    return np.ndarray.flatten(mfcc)[:25000]

def generate_features_and_labels():
    all_features = []
    all_labels = []
    genres = ['blues', 'classical', 'country', 'disco', 'hiphop', 
    'jazz', 'metal', 'pop', 'reggae', 'rock']
    for genre in genres:
        sound_files = glob.glob('genres/'+genre+'/*.au')
        print('Processing %d songs in %s genre...' % 
        (len(sound_files), genre))
        for f in sound_files:
            features = extract_features_song(f)
            all_features.append(features)
            all_labels.append(genre)

    label_uniq_ids, label_row_ids = np.unique(all_labels, 
    return_inverse=True)
    label_row_ids = label_row_ids.astype(np.int32, copy=False)
    onehot_labels = to_categorical(label_row_ids,   
    len(label_uniq_ids))
    return np.stack(all_features), onehot_labels


features, labels = generate_features_and_labels()

print(np.shape(features))
print(np.shape(labels))

training_split = 0.8

alldata = np.column_stack((features, labels))
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.20,  
random_state=37)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
  X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
  y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]


print(np.shape(train))
print(np.shape(test))

train_input = test[:,:-10]
train_labels = train[:,-10:]

test_input = test[:,:-10]
test_labels = test[:,-10:]

print(np.shape(train_input))
print(np.shape(train_labels))

model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_dim=np.shape(train_input)[1]),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
    ])


 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(train_input, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32,
          validation_split=0.2) 

loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_input, test_labels, batch_size=32)

print('Done!')
print('Loss: %.4f, accuracy: %.4f' % (loss, acc))
```

Python began to provide the expected response, producing:

```
Processing 100 songs in blues genre...
Processing 100 songs in classical genre...
Processing 100 songs in country genre...
Processing 100 songs in disco genre...
Processing 100 songs in hiphop genre...
Processing 100 songs in jazz genre...
Processing 100 songs in metal genre...
Processing 100 songs in pop genre...
Processing 100 songs in reggae genre...
Processing 100 songs in rock genre...
(1000, 25000)
(1000, 10)
```

But interrupted the process and displayed this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/surengrigorian/Documents/Stage1.py", line 60, in     <module>
    for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide concerning this issue.

Answer (score 0):

X and y are not defined in your code, I belive that in your case X is equal to features and Y is equal to labels

```
X=features
y=labels

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

hope it helps